# How do I create a custom animation in windows using the windows api?

Tags: c++, windows, api, animation, loading

I am using C++, on windows using only the windows api.

What I'm trying to create is a circle loading animation type of thing. Similar to the animation thats displayed on the left side of a tab, in IE when you try to load a page.
In fact I'm curious how programmers create animations like those at all.

If anyone could explain how thats done, and maybe provide tutorial links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like that, you would typically create a series of icons, set a timer to cycle through them at the desired rate, then kill the timer when the animation was no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please see MSJ (now called MSDN Magazine) on September 1999. Dr. Paul Dilascia will tell you how to do what you want. Here is the link: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/c/c0999.aspx